# Runtime explanation

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory

Can someone please explain to me why the recursive part of this algorithm has the runtime

T(n) = {O(1), if n ≤ 3;
       {Tf(n/2) + Tc(n/2) + O(n), if n > 3.

->where Tf(n/2) represents the floor function of T(n/2) and Tc(n/2) represents the the ceilling function????

The algorithm  is called Shamos  and the main steps are:

1. If n ≤ 3 find the closest points by brute force and stop.
2. Find a vertical line V such that divides the input set into two disjoint subsets PL and PR of size
   as equal as possible . Points to the left or on the line
   belong PL and points to the right or on the line belong to PR. No point belongs to both since
   the sets are disjoint.
3. Recursively find the distance δL of a closest pair of points in PL and the distance δR of a closest
   pair in PR.
4. Let δ = min(δL, δR). The distance of a pair of closest points in the input set P is either that of
   the points found in the recursive step (i.e., δ) or consists of the distance between a point in PL
   and a point in PR.

   (a) The only candidate points one from PL and one from PR must be in a vertical strip consisting
   of a line at distance δ to the left of the line V and a line at distance δ to the right of V

   (b) Let YV be an array of the points within the strip sorted by non-decreasing y coordinate
   (i.e., if i ≤ j then YV [i] ≤ YV [j]).

   (c) Starting with the first point in YV and stepping trough all except the last, check the distance
   of this point with the next 7 points (or any that are left if there are not as many as 7). If a
   pair is found with distance strictly less than δ then assign this distance to δ.
5. Return δ.
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: Before you get into the run-time of the algorithm, do you understand what it is supposed to do?  Do you see how it works?

Comment: @Justin Good (starting) point. :-)

Comment: it uses a conceptual sweep line  and recursion to find the closest points in the Euclidean space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T(c(n/2))` and `T(f(n/2))` describe how much time it takes to call the algorithm recursively on the left and right groups, respectively, since half of the points have been placed in each group.

`O(n)` comes from the tricky part of the algorithm: after the recursive calls, we have found δ, namely the distance between the closest pair of points either in the left group or in the right group. Now we want to look for pairs consisting of one point from the left group and one point from the right group. Of course, there is little use in looking at points that are further away than δ from the middle line. However, it could still be that all points are within δ of the middle line, so it looks like we risk having to compare `n^2` point pairs. The important observation now is that precisely because we know that in each group, no pair of points is closer than δ, we know that there is a small, constant worst-case limit to how many points from the right group we need to look at for each pair in the left group. So if we can only get our points sorted on their y-coordinates, we can find the closest pair in linear time. It's possible to obtain this sorted list in linear time due to the way the list is passed between the recursive calls, but the details escape me (feel free to fill in, anyone).